# HTML Serviceをiframeで他サイトに埋め込む方法

Tags: google-apps-script

Google Apps ScriptでテンプレートHTMLを作成し、doGetで表示。そのスクリプトのURLをiframeで指定して他サイトから表示することは可能でしょうか？

index.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <?
    var site = sitesApp.getPageByUrl("https://sites.google.com/...");
    var contents = site.getHtmlContent();
    output.append(contents);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

code.gs

```
function doGet() {
    var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index");
    return html.evaluate;
}
```

Comment: あなたは力の印刷を使用する必要があります`<？！=...？>`  [Googleのドキュメント：](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#force-printing_scriptlets)  これを試して：`<?!= SitesApp.getPageByUrl(url).getHtmlContent() ?>`

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
提案いただいたコードを試してみたのですが、自分のサイトのiframeで表示することができませんでした。
`<?!=...?>`はどういった場合に用いるものなんでしょうか？
`<?=...?>`を使うことがなぜできないのか、なぜ自分のサイトで表示することができないのかを教えていただきたいです。

Thanks for commenting!
I tried it but I couldn't display the HTML page on my website.
I'm not sure what does `<?!=...?>` mean.
I want to know Why I cannot use `<?=...?>` , and why I cannot display the page on my website?

Answer (score 2):

今の所は出来なさそうですね。
[X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)という物があり、これを使うとWebページが他のサイトのiframeに埋め込まれるのを防ぐ事が出来ます。
試しにHTML Serviceを作りアクセスして見ると、応答ヘッダに

```
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

が含まれていました。app scriptはセキュリティ上の配慮が様々とられているようで、ここも制限されているのでしょう。
いずれ条件付きで許可される事があるかも知れませんし、既に制限を解除する方法があるのかも知れませんが、ドキュメントにはそういった記述は無さそうです。

Google Sitesに埋め込む事は出来るので、それでやって欲しいという事でしょう。

---

追記:
Google Sitesで作ったサイトは設定で`X-Frame-Options`の制限を外す事が出来ます。
ですから、Google Sitesのページ自体は他のドメインのページにiframeで埋め込み可能です。
しかし、それに埋め込んだHTML Serviceは相変らず`X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`です。

ではなぜGoogle Sitesに埋め込めるかというと、Google Sitesに埋め込んだHTML Serviceは**script**.google.comではなく、 **sites**.google.com ドメインから配信されるからです。
これによって`X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`の制限を回避しています。

よって『「HTML Serviceを埋め込んだGoogle Sites」を埋め込んだ外部ドメインのページ』ではGoogle Sitesの部分は表示され、その中のHTML Serviceの部分は表示されない、という現象が起こります。

(こういった事情は刻々と変るので、いつまでこうなっているかは分かりません。念の為)

Comment: やっぱり制限がかかってるんですよね...わかりました。
Googleサイトに埋め込んだHTML Serviceをiframeで表示することも不可能でしょうか？

Comment: 無理な筈です。追記しておきました。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。